# Find all points between two given points in 3D using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Is there a function in Matlab that I can get all the points along a straight line between two given points in 3D? It's somehow similar to plot3() function but instead of visualizing it I want to get all the points between this two point point1(x,y,z) and point2(o,m,n) so I can use them to do calculation? I figured out how to do it in 2D but there are so many directions need to be considered in 3D ..
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a sampling of the points between the specified coordinates, or maybe all points contained in a specific data set? Because otherwise you're asking for "all" of an infinite set of points. Please clarify.

Comment: Uncountable infinity, I should add. Are you sure you want _all_ of them? :-)

Comment: thanks for the reminder! I actually only need the integer coordinates, tried uint8() the result but the line isn't straight anymore :'(  any idea? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the line joining the points, parameterised by `t`. To get more points on the line, decrease the spacing in `t`.

```
point1=[1 2 3];
point2=[5 5 5];
t=0:.01:1;
C=repmat(point1,length(t),1)'+(point2-point1)'*t
```

Answer (score 0):

The math does not change with additional dimensions. All points on the line between A and B are defined by:

`(A-B).*x+B`

With `0<x<1` you have the segment between A and B